# Query object and return embedded documents that the `_id` field is not part of a list

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have defined the following Question object as a Schema in mongoose:

```
const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    text: String,
})
```

That will be used by a Quizz

```
const QuizzSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    questions: [QuestionSchema],
});
```

And then in another Model I save the relation between questions completed by each user:

```
const QuizzStateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: ObjectId,  //References the user
    quizzId: ObjectId, //References the Quizz
    questionState: {
        type: Map,
        of: {
            correct: Boolean,
        }
    }
});
```

So as you can see, a `Quizz` contains an array of questions. And when this questions are done by the user, the questions are added to the `questionState` of the `QuizzState` that corresponds to that user and quizz. I made `questionState` a map because it is easier to manage in the frontend.

Now I'm trying to retrieve the questions of a quizz that the user has not completed yet, this means the questions that are part of `questions` array in `Quizz` but not in the `questionState` map.

So having the corresponding `quizz` and `quizzState` objects, I can get all the completed questions with `quizzState.questionState.keys()`. And I could iterate over the `questions` array and remove them if they exist in `quizzState.questionState.keys()` but that seems really hardcore thinking there could be thousands of questions in a quizz.

Is there any way of telling Mongoose:
**Query this object and return the embedded documents that their ID is not in this list**

Query a Quizz and return the questions that their ID is not part of `quizzState.questionState.keys()`.

I am using MongoDB 4.4.15 and Mongoose 6.4.

Comment: You can use the MongoDB aggregation `$lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the only solution I have come up with is:

1. Get the keys into an array:

```
var idsArr = [];
for(const id of quizzState.questionState.keys()){
    idsArr.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
}
```

2. Perform and aggregation with a projection. This projection will filter the array and check only for questions where the `_id` field is not in the list. This is where I was having troubles, because I was trying to use `$nin` operator which didn't work with the filter, so I ended up using `$not`+ `$in`:

```
docs = await Quizz.aggregate()
    .match({"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(quizzId)})
    .project({
        questions: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$questions",
                as: "questions",
                cond: { $not : { $in: ['$$questions._id', idsArr]}}
            }
        }
    })
```

I am not sure this is the optimal solution. I think the match will check the whole collection instead of performing a `findOne`, but couldn't figure out how to change this behavior. In my case it's not the worst since there will only be a few documents in this collection.

Apart from that, with my approach I need to perform two different queries, assuming I already have the QuizzId (otherwise it would be 3). Maybe the model could be rearranged to fix this. But really can't think of how.

I am keeping the answer open in case someone can propose a better solution.